# DNN Skin - Bootstrap v4.1.1 - Settings for empty container being displayed

Tags: bootstrap-4, dotnetnuke

I'm working on a BS4 DNN Skin.  At the bottom of the page, I have a fluid container which will sometimes house information.  When it does, it displays information in the proper container without any issue.

But if there is nothing to be displayed, the settings of the outer container are still being shown ever so slightly; the background color and border.

Is there a way to prevent this?  Thank you..

```
CSS:
.bottompagelinks { background-color:#60584B; border-top:2px dotted #000; }

<div class="container-fluid bottompagelinks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" runat="server" id="Row_Grid3_Pane1" />
      <div class="col-md-3" runat="server" id="Row_Grid3_Pane2" />
      <div class="col-md-3" runat="server" id="Row_Grid3_Pane3" />
      <div class="col-md-3" runat="server" id="Row_Grid3_Pane4" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create panes like this, within a row within a container, I like to not apply many styles (if any) to the row and container. Along side that, I apply `padding: 0` to any empty panes, so that the empty panes do not affect the way their parents are rendered.

With your code, I'm assuming that if all the panes were empty, you'd still have the applied Bootstrap padding to the columns, the row, and the container.